# \bm creates doubled letters

Tags: symbols, bold, bm

I have used `\bm` for my math symbols, that are vectors. However, after PDF export, I can see after zoom double letters. Is this normal behaviour of `\bm` or something is messed up, because it look ugly?

[image]

I have found, that this issue is caused by 3rd party package dfadobe:

```
\usepackage{dfadobe}
\usepackage{bm}
```

If I remove dfadobe, doubled text is gone. But I can not remove dfadobe, since it is part of template I have to use.

Comment: bm will drop back to overprinting as a last resort if it can't think of anything better to do, but I wouldn't expect it to do that for an F. It _always_ helps if you include a test document in the question so it can be debugged.

Comment: I have edited question

Comment: @Martin Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: The edit doesn't really help! a test document should start `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` how can I debug just two lines? also you gave no link to "dfadobe" I found one at  http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~blob/502/egPublStyle-CGF/dfadobe.sty  if it is that, it is basically a version of the standard mathptm package which uses a very simple setup which does not provide any bold math fonts so bm has nothing it can do other than overprint.

Comment: oh they are not doubled, they are tripled:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bm` will in preference use the fonts specified for `\boldmath` to produce bold symbols in the standard math setup, however if there are no bold fonts available, or if it has run out of slots, then it will fall back to faking bold via overprinting.

The `dfadobe` package you are using seems to be a variant of the original `mathptm` package, which was designed to just use the fonts available on the first apple/sun laserwriter PostScript printers. It disables `\boldmath`:

```
\def\boldmath{%
\@warning{there is no bold Symbol font}%
\global\let\boldmath=\relax
}
```

and loads no bold math fonts.

As such `bm` has no bold fonts available to use.

Certainly this is *not* the recommended way to get times-like fonts in text or math these days,

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

for example would give a far more complete set of fonts.

However if using `dfadobe` font setup is a requirement of your submission, it is what it is, that implies a requirement to have no real bold math fonts, so fake bold (or no bold) is the only alternative.